# Login via CIVIC on Client side with Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I need to create a login via CIVIC with Reactjs, looks like, I'm unable to access civic global variable, I'm following the docs https://docs.civic.com/#Browse , any idea what I may be doing wrong. I move the script link to the top of the html body, and to the bottom and I got the same error message. Thanks.

I'm getting this error " Line 4: 'civic' is not defined no-undef "

```
/public/index.html

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>React App</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://hosted-sip.civic.com/css/civic-modal.min.css">
    <script src="https://hosted-sip.civic.com/js/civic.sip.min.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
/CivicLogin.js

import React from 'react';

const CivicLogin = () => {  
  var civicSip = new civic.sip({ appId: 'myAppID' });

  return (
    <button id="signupButton" class="civic-button-a medium" type="button">
      <span>Log in with Civic</span>
    </button>

  );
}


export default CivicLogin;
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add window to civic.sip, so the global variable can be read it from window object, found it here https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/using-global-variables

```
/CivicLogin.js

import React from 'react';

const CivicLogin = () => {  
  var civicSip = new window.civic.sip({ appId: 'myAppID' });

  return (
    <button id="signupButton" class="civic-button-a medium" type="button">
      <span>Log in with Civic</span>
    </button>

  );
}


export default CivicLogin;
```